# Running parametrize pytests in VS Code sometimes runs in parallel, is there a setting to prevent this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest

When running pytest using the VS Code testing framework, depending on how I trigger a parametrized test, it either runs in parallel (multiple test sessions), or in series (one test session).

Previously (older VS Code versions) I believe it always ran in series. Is there a setting for this?

When I call it from the Test Explorer (1), it runs in series.
When I call the test from the Editor (2), it runs in parallel.

[image]

I added pytest arg '-rP' to observe output.
environment: Python 3.8.10, pytest 6.2.5, VS Code 1.67.1,

Example test:

```
import pytest
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

@pytest.mark.parametrize("descriptor", ["test1", "test2", "test3"])
def test_first(descriptor):
    print("start {0}: {1}".format(descriptor, datetime.now()))
    sleep(10)
    print("end {0}: {1}".format(descriptor, datetime.now()))
```

Example output running from Test Explorer (1):

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\Github\test
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 3 items

test_parallel_or_series.py ...                                           [100%]

=================================== PASSES ====================================
______________________________ test_first[test1] ______________________________
---------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
start test1: 2022-05-11 11:29:50.078870
end test1: 2022-05-11 11:30:00.083041
______________________________ test_first[test2] ______________________________
---------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
start test2: 2022-05-11 11:30:00.092023
end test2: 2022-05-11 11:30:10.093613
______________________________ test_first[test3] ______________________________
---------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
start test3: 2022-05-11 11:30:10.095437
end test3: 2022-05-11 11:30:20.099773
- generated xml file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-139884Q1NL33DkM8E.xml -
============================= 3 passed in 30.07s ==============================
```

Example output running from Editor (2):

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\Github\test
plugins: cov-3.0.0
rootdir: c:\Github\test
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 1 item

test_parallel_or_series.py collected 1 item

test_parallel_or_series.py rootdir: c:\Github\test
plugins: cov-3.0.0
collected 1 item

test_parallel_or_series.py ...                                             [100%]                                             [100%]                                             [100%]

=================================== PASSES ====================================
______________________________ test_first[test2] ______________________________
---------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
start test2: 2022-05-11 11:29:04.905957
end test2: 2022-05-11 11:29:14.913812


- generated xml file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-13988TVCwRoFnH3Ys.xml -
============================= 1 passed in 10.06s ==============================
=================================== PASSES ====================================
______________________________ test_first[test3] ______________________________
---------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
start test3: 2022-05-11 11:29:04.905957
end test3: 2022-05-11 11:29:14.913812


- generated xml file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-13988GLF4W4rdCe5N.xml -
=================================== PASSES ====================================
______________________________ test_first[test1] ______________________________
---------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
start test1: 2022-05-11 11:29:04.911930
end test1: 2022-05-11 11:29:14.913812
- generated xml file: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-13988xfPcGZdiQWs9.xml -
============================= 1 passed in 10.06s ==============================
============================= 1 passed in 10.06s ==============================
```

Comment: I can't believe there are no responses to this even with so many up votes. I opened a github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An upcoming release includes a rewrite of the test framework. Running tests with the new framework no longer results in the observed behaviour. Instead tests run as expected, serially in a single test session.

You can run the new framework before its official release by:

> add this setting to your users settings.json
> "python.experiments.optInto": ["pythonTestAdapter"]

Further details in the [issue card](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21529).
Thanks to @red888 for reporting this on the vscode-python repo.